# How to display images from API using Fetch API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fetch-api

First of all, I'm working with the [Unofficial Xbox API](https://xboxapi.com/) and I'm trying to display the images from the endpoint example [CLICK HERE](https://xboxapi.com/v2/screenshots/1144039928) that is provided inn the website.

So I'm using a button with callback to a Fetch API function:

```js
document.getElementById('getScreenshots').addEventListener('click', getScreenshots);
    
    function getScreenshots(){
        // Get data from URL
        fetch('https://xboxapi.com/v2/screenshots/1144039928',{
            headers: new Headers({
                "X-Auth": "HERE-GOES-MY-API-KEY",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            })
        })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            let output = '<h5>List of Recent Screenshots</h5>';
            data.forEach(function(screenshot){
                output += `
                    <ul>
                        <li>ID: ${screenshot.screenshotId}</li>
                        <li>Published at: ${screenshot.datePublished}</li>
                        <li><img src="${screenshot.uri}"></li>
                    </ul>
                `;
            });
            document.getElementById('screenshots').innerHTML = output;
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))
    }
```

```html
        <button id="getScreenshots">Get Screenshots</button>
        <ul id="screenshots"></ul>
```

but everytime that I try to request it, the images are not shown and the console trows me an error of 404 for each image. Here is what I'm talking about:
[image]

Can anybody help me with this?.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE, this is the json data that I get when using Postman:

```
"thumbnails": [
    {
        "uri": "https://screenshotscontent-t5002.xboxlive.com/xuid-2535443387655711-public/29cd392a-6758-4926-8396-44aa77822ac6_Thumbnail.PNG",
        "fileSize": 0,
        "thumbnailType": "Small"
    },
    {
        "uri": "https://screenshotscontent-t5002.xboxlive.com/xuid-2535443387655711-public/29cd392a-6758-4926-8396-44aa77822ac6_Thumbnail.PNG",
        "fileSize": 0,
        "thumbnailType": "Large"
    }
],
"screenshotUris": [
    {
        "uri": "https://screenshotscontent-d5002.xboxlive.com/xuid-2535443387655711-private/29cd392a-6758-4926-8396-44aa77822ac6.PNG?sv=2015-12-11&sr=b&si=DefaultAccess&sig=5Is2Shl9m0c85yI0Vq%2BTRs3cuwYDvUR2BBWrD2%2FpkIw%3D",
        "fileSize": 1255362,
        "uriType": "Download",
        "expiration": "2018-08-29 04:51:56"
    }
],
"xuid": 2535443387655711,
"screenshotName": "",
"titleName": "Halo: The Master Chief Collection",
"screenshotLocale": "en-US",
"screenshotContentAttributes": "None",
"deviceType": "Durango",
"screenshotDetails": "https://xboxapi.com/v2/2535443387655711/screenshot-details/d1adc8aa-0a31-4407-90f2-7e9b54b0347c/29cd392a-6758-4926-8396-44aa77822ac6"
```

},

Comment: Are you sure `screenshot.uri` is defined? Could you provide API response JSON?

Comment: It was actually wrong, the right endpoint was screenshot.screenshotUris.uri but I stll get a 404 for each image... Check my updated question.

Comment: `screenshot.screenshotUris.uri` will be undefined because `screenshot.screenshotUris` is an array. So you need `screenshot.screenshotUris[0].uri` or making a cycle like `screenshot.screenshotUris.forEach(function(el) { ...el.uri... })`

Comment: OMG, I would have never figured it out by myself. Big thanks. Can you copy and paste your comment to mark it an answer?....up to you but its solved now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`screenshot.screenshotUris.uri` will be undefined because `screenshot.screenshotUris` is an array. So you need:

`screenshot.screenshotUris[0].uri`

or making a cycle like

`screenshot.screenshotUris.forEach(function(el) { ...el.uri... })`